# Show image overlay if hover a div

Tags: html, css, elementor

I have created a addon for elementor. I have card, html markup is as below:

```
        <div class="card">
            <div class="header">
                <img src="img.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>some content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have added overlay on image to show when image get hover, by using elementor overlay background type control. **For elementor selector I am using {{wrapper .header img:hover:before}}.** On hover image overlay showing fine but  now I want image overlay should also appear if div class card get hovered, **by using CSS**

Comment: See this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp

Answer (score 1):

**You need to do following this steps:-**

image overlay if hover a  div tag

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2>Fade in Overlay</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[html](/questions/tagged/html)  [css](/questions/tagged/css)   [mayurpathak](/questions/tagged/mayurpathak)

Comment: Finally I got this solution: 'selector' =>  $wrapper.".etlms-card:hover .tutor-course-header:before "

Comment: welcome @SKShewa